# Why bootstrap file is not loading when i add double mapping in href?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

```
     <!-- this working fine, load all bootstrap files -->
      <li class="nav-item" id="products">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/productlist">Products</a>
      </li>
     <!-- this failed to laod bootstap file when i add one more /string in href -->
        <li class="nav-item" id="products">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/productlist/id">Products</a>
      </li>



#working fine
@RequestMapping(value= "/productlist")
public ModelAndView productlist() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("categoryList", categoryService.getAllCategory());
    mv.setViewName("products");
    return mv;
}
#failed to load bootstrap file
@RequestMapping(value= "/productlist/id")
public ModelAndView product() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("categoryList", categoryService.getAllCategory());
    mv.setViewName("products");
    return mv;
}
```

When I put href="/productlist/id", my code is failed to load bootstrap file but it working fine in case of href="productlist"

Failed to load bootstrap file

Answer (score 0):

I changed static file path and add slash before the path.

before

```
<script src="assets/js/myapp.js"></script>
```

after

```
<script src="/assets/js/myapp.js"></script>
```